# Get json data from api -> Parse html inside an attribute to a new object-structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have a very specific problem. I am building a custom frontend for a internal Document Management System, i get some date using the JSON-API of the DMS, but need to get some more parameters for the frontend.
The Team that works with the software agreed to use an existing text-parameter "description" for these values and started adding a block like "" to the beginning of most documents.

I'm working with jquery and monkberry right now on a simple frontend. This mostly works, but my colleagues wish for some more features... the most they wish for is a folder structure, with at least 2 levels.
I told them to add the attribute-parameter "folder=''" and filling in the structure like they know from computers, given the example "folder='topfolder/subfolder'". Now i need to parse this somehow :D
What would be the best way, to parse a structure like this:

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "name": "Document A",
      "description": "<attribute folder='topfolderA/subfolder1' visible='' tags='' />This is just a text",
      "scope": "Public",
      "id": "9fcf8270d6d546419a555c4c6fd0ccd5"
    },
    {
      "name": "Document B",
      "description": "<attribute folder='topfolderB/subfolder2' visible='' tags='' />This is just the normal descriptioon Text",
      "scope": "Public",
      "id": "331338eb001c4a48ae3bb164653ae596"
    },
    {
      "name": "Document C",
      "description": "No description written yet",
      "scope": "Private",
      "id": "331338eb001c422easeeseessa3ae596"
    }
  ],
  "about": {
    "roles": [
      "Admin",
      "Author"
    ]
  }
}
```

to an object / array structure i can iterate through, like

```
- folder A
--- subfolder 1
------ Document I
--- subfolder 2
------ Document II
--- Document III
--- Document IV

- folder B
--- subfolder 3
------ Document V
------ Document VI
--- subfolder 4
------ Document VII
--- Document VIII
```

(each document object contains the data values)

Any ideas how to do this in vanilla js and / or jQuery? :)

Thanks in advance

Thomas

Comment: How can we determine which document goes to which folder ?

Comment: the folder the document belongs to, is in the "<attribute folder='topfolder/subfolder' />" in the description :)

Comment: The object you show us only has a list of documents without folder attribute

Comment: i sadly can't change the API of the DMS to add the folder attribute. so we decided to put a parameter-block into the description attribute. take a look at documents -> Document A -> Description

Comment: Ok I miss this part sorry. I understand now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do a simple regex search while parsing.

Some sample code snippet:

```
 const regex = /folder\='([a-z,A-Z,0-9,\/]*)'/g;
 const str = `<attribute folder='topfolderA/subfolder1' visible='' tags='' />`;
 var m = regex.exec(str);
```

`m` is a [result array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and it would look something like `["folder='topfolderA/subfolder1'", "topfolderA/subfolder1"]` for the example. The array's first element is the entire regex match and elements in the following indices are paranthesized matches that we save. We can use `()` to save matches while doing regex searching.

Once you have the path which would be in this case just:

```
 var path = m[1];
 var structure = path.split('/');
 //structure array would have sequence of folders and subfolders you'd have to create.
```

I have saved a demo of the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/HxVHmo/1). Feel free to play around with it and modify it to suit your needs. The regular expression I used `/folder\='([a-z,A-Z,0-9,\/]*)'/g` basically looks for the string `"folder"` followed by either alphabets numbers or forward slashes (folder structures could contain other things also, you can define it within `[]`. I surround the folder path with `()` as we need to access this path. The flag `g` at the end suggests that the search is global. You can also add the flag `i` which would make the matching case insensitive. Good starting point for regex in javascript is the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: But how do i do the next step, to create the object-structure, with the folders, and documents therein (and at the same level)?